# Prove linearly independence of column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be nonzero nilpotent matrix, that is $A^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$.

Let $u_o\in M_{n,1}{(\mathbb{R})}$ be such that $A^{k-1}u_o\neq0$. Show that $Au_o$ and $u_o$ are linearly independent.

The following is what I try:

Suppose $Au_o$ and $u_o$ are linearly dependent. This implies that 
$$Au_o=\lambda u_o,\lambda\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$$

$$A^{k-1}Au_o=\lambda A^{k-1}u_o\implies A^{k-1}u_o=0$$

which leads to contradiction.

But my friend points out that if $Au_o$ is zero, the equation that I established is not true.

Comment: If $Au_0$ is $0$, what does that say about $A^{k-1}u_0 = A^{k-2}(Au_0)$?

Comment: So should I separate into two cases for $A^{k-1}u_o$ in order to make the proof complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your last point: If $Au_0$ is zero, then so is $A^k u_0$ for all $k\ge 1$.  That would be contrary to your given conditions.